# How to distribute a value into vector

Tags: c++, c++11, visual-c++

Hi i need help to distribute a value into a vector and print all possible combination for example
If a user input first value that will be the vector size input1size = 15;
Then input2 is the value going to distribute inside the vector . input2 =25;
3rd input is first constant value of the vector input3 = 2 ; then this value minus input2 is the value i need to distribute inside vector

After the distribution vector look like this . When we add vector
Data together the output need to be = to input2 = 25 ; and the first value is user input3;

```
 V1 = {2,9,2,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1} = 25;
 V1 = {2,9,1,2,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1} = 25;
 V1 = {2,9,1,1,2,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1} = 25;
  .........
 V1 = {2,1,1,1,1,1,1,8,1,1,1,1,1,1,3} = 25;
```

So on ..... and find all sequences 
How can i do this ...

Comment: and this question applies to all languages that has a "C" in it?

Comment: @artm I don't see Javascript in the tags though.

Comment: Is there any chance you could attempt to make the question a little clearer. I have no idea what you're asking.  Perhaps you can show what you've tried so far, and when it's going wrong if appropriate;  what is input1size etc?

Comment: basically, you want all possible vector of size input1 countaining natural integers, where the first element is input3 and the sum of all the elements is input2 ?

Comment: sadly, in given unclear conditions, there is infinite amount of answers. Example: size 3, sum 5, first 2: {2,0,3}, {2,1,2}, {2,2,1}, {2,3,0}, {2,4,-1}, {2,5,-2}, {2,6,-3} ... Of course we are limited by integer size. Question is unclear.

Comment: Try to clarify your question... Give a part of your code, because right now we cannot understand what you are asking.

Comment: @BlackMoses it's not clear but it's possible to guess from the example given that there are only stricly positive integers

Comment: This vector have 15 values and its sum is the input2 that is 25 this 25 distribute in to this vector and also the 3rd input3 is 2 is defined by users so that is the the first value in the vector its mean 25 - 2 = 23 is the value we going to distribute insiad the vector  . What i wnat is to find the all possible combination  that give total vector sum = 25 , i need to print out that is it . Sorry for my English is too bad i dont have any others options pls help

Comment: @BlackMoses  zeros and negative number not allowed

Comment: Have you try something ? Almost an idea of algorithm ?

Answer (score 0):

Something like that? Didn't optimize it though (ugly recursion).

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <deque>
#include <algorithm>

std::vector<std::deque<int>> getcombo(int a, std::deque<int> combo = {})
{
    int sum = std::accumulate(combo.begin(), combo.end(), 0);
    std::vector<std::deque<int>> output;
    std::deque<int> extcombo;
    if(sum == a)
    {
        return std::vector<std::deque<int>> ({combo});
    }
    else
    {
        for(int i=1; i<a+1; ++i)
        {
            if(sum + i <= a)
            {
                extcombo = combo;
                extcombo.push_back(i);
                for(auto c : getcombo(a, extcombo))
                    output.push_back(c);
            }
        }
    }
    return output;
}

std::vector<std::deque<int>> final_combo(size_t size, int sum, int first)
{
    --size;
    auto final = getcombo(sum-first);
    auto new_end = std::remove_if(final.begin(), final.end(),
                                  [size](auto deq) {return deq.size() != size;});
    final.erase(new_end, final.end());

    for(auto&& x : final)
        x.push_front(first);
    return final;
}

int main()
{
    for (auto x : final_combo(5, 11, 4))
    {
        for(auto y : x)
            std::cout << y << ", ";
        std::cout << std::endl;
    }
}
```